# Why does my Code-128 Barcode Encoder not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, barcode, code128

So, I have a block of text in which there is a barcode. For this I use the Code128 font to display text as a barcode. But it doesn't work that easy with Code 128. So I took the following Encode in the hope that my text would be changed into a scannable barcode. however for some reason i still can't read it.

```
 public string BarcodeEncode(string value)
    {
        int[] overChars = { 8216, 8217, 8220, 8221, 8226, 8211, 8212, 732, 8364 };
        char[] valueChars = value.ToCharArray();
        int[] checksumVals = new int[value.Length];

        for (int n = 0; n < valueChars.Length; n++)
        {
            checksumVals[n] = (((byte)valueChars[n]) - 32) * (n + 1);
        }

        int checksum = checksumVals.Sum() % 103;
        char check = (char)(checksum + 33);
        if (checksum > 93)
            check = (char)overChars[checksum - 94];

        string start = ((char)353).ToString();
        string stop = ((char)339).ToString();

        return start + value + check.ToString() + stop;
    }
```

Bevor this decoding my BarCode lookslike that:

[image: Before]

But I cant scan it with an barcode scanner.

So I did the following method, in the hope that with this change I will be able to scan the barcode with a Bacode scanner.

But after that my Barcode looks like that:

[image: Barcode2]

And it doesnt work either

The Input of my Barcode is just a text  "Hellooo" nothing special yet

Comment: If I get it right, this code calculates a checksum and then produces a result by concatenation. It it that your checkum is not correct? or what does "I cannot read it" mean? Please give some sample input, the expected and the observed output.

Comment: I editet the Question, may that will help you better to understand my Problem

Comment: Code-128 isn't just a "one character, one line pattern" code, you need to *encode* your value first, and how to encode that value depends on the particular font used. If you need a barcode where you can just output an arbitrary string with a font and be done, use 3of9 instead (google for Free3of9 for one such font).